# Any way to prove that any uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ must contain an interval $[a, b)$?

Tags: general-topology

This seems pretty intuitively obvious, but how would I go about proving that any uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$  must contain an uncountable interval $[a, b)$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Take the Cantor set for a counterexample. Or the irrationals in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 7):

The rationals are *dense* in ${\mathbb R}$. So if you look at ${\mathbb R} \setminus {\mathbb Q}$, that contains no open subset of ${\mathbb R}$, so in particular it contains no interval $(a,b)$. It's still uncountable, though. So the claim is false.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, take the Cantor set for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set . It does not contain any interval, by construction, but it is uncountable. In fact it's even worse, the Cantor set has measure 0 (so it contains no interval by corollary) and it's still uncountable.